# Why hibernate doesn't throw exception if there is no getter & setter in entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, jpa

I have  1 entity class without getter and setter.

I have 4 records in the db. when I try to create rest service and query these data from db, hibernate returns 4 empty elements.

```
[{},{},{},{},{}]
```

Hibernate tries to set records into entity but fails because there is no setter method.

So why hibernate doesn't throw exception like "there is no setter, setting is failed..." it is trying to set and returning empty list.

tell me the reason, is this a bug or it returns error in different log path which i don't know?

Edit: Here is the Entity.class

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "entry_table", schema = "public")
public class Entry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ENTRY_ID")
    private Long entryId;

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "USER_ENTRY")
    private String userEntry;

    public Entry(Long entryId, String userName, String userEntry) {
        this.entryId = entryId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userEntry = userEntry;
    }

    public Entry() {

    }
}
```

Comment: `Hibernate tries to set records into entity but fails because there is no setter method.` How do you know that hibernate is trying to set the values but failing bcos of lack of setters? Are the instance variables accesible or private?

Comment: Is this [{},{},{},{},{}] the response from REST api or you inspected your DAO layer?

Comment: Are the instance variables of the entity class accessible from outside? For saving a new entity instance in the DB, how are you populating these instance variables?

Comment: Can you post your entity class?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu because it returns empty list.

Comment: @Rohit it is the REST response from browser.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is it is NOT A BUG.

As you can see from the doc [Declare getters and setters for persistent attributes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch02.html#domainmodel-pojo-accessors)

> Standard, portable JPA essentially requires this. Otherwise your model
>   would violate the requirement quoted above in regards to accessing the
>   entity persistent state fields directly from outside the entity
>   itself.
>
> Although Hibernate does not require it, it is recommended to follow
>   JavaBean conventions by defining getters and setters for you entities
>   persistent attributes. You can still tell Hibernate to directly access
>   the entity's fields.

You were getting empty elements because you might not expose any fields of the entity class to the outside world. So it is normal.

From the [Access strategies](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/access.html) doc

> Advantage of using field-based access is that some entity attributes
>   can be hidden from outside the entity. An example of such attribute is
>   the entity @Version field, which must not be manipulated by the data
>   access layer. With field-based access, we can simply omit the getter
>   and the setter for this version field, and Hibernate can still
>   leverage the optimistic concurrency control mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The empty rest response is due to JSON serialization not finding the accessors in the entity. You will need `getters` for all property atleast for the JSON serialization to work and show correct response.

Hibernate correctly populates the entities and sends them to your REST layer.